# Find the probability of number plates.

Tags: probability-theory

> A licence plate consists of a sequence of seven symbols:
>
> ```
>   number, letter, letter,letter, number, number, number,
> ```
>
> where a letter is any one of $26$ letters and a number is one
>   among $0,1,\ldots,9$.  Assume that all licence plates are equally likely.
>
> (a) What is the probability
>   that all symbols are different?
>
> (b) What is the probability that all symbols are different and the
>   first number is the largest among the numbers?

My solution:

(a) Since there are four places for numbers and three positions for letters. So the total outcome will be $10^4\times26^3$. Now since all the numbers and letters should be distinct, so the required probability is
$$\frac{10\times9\times8\times7\times26\times25\times24}{10^426^3}.$$

(b) In this case since the first number should be the largest among the numbers so the probability of being the largest among $4$ numbers is $\frac{1}{4}$. So multiplying the result in (a) with $\frac{1}{4}$ will give the result.

Am I correct with the solutions? Specifically with (b)? Thanks.

Comment: it seem to be the case. because if you draw 4 different numbers , there are 4! options to order them. if you force the highest to be the first. you are left with different ordering of 3 numbers which is 3!. so indeed $\frac{3!}{4!} = \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: At $(a)$ you haven´t regarded that the distinct numbers and letters can be ordered in different ways. Therefore you have to multiply your result with $3!\cdot 4!$

Comment: @callculus: Yes he has. It is already "taken care of" (i.e., it is "embedded" in the numerator).

Comment: @callculus, I think he is fine. if you multiply by 3!*4! you end with number higher than 1.

Comment: @d_e You are right.

Comment: Just a heads up for those who might be misinterpreting the question like I did. In part (b), they are not asking to fix the first number position with the largest number (which would be 9). They're asking that among the numbers drawn, what is the probability that the first is the largest - so (5, 4, 3, 2) is a valid favorable outcome, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  Another slightly more complicated approach is that once you have selected the digits, there are $4!$ ways to order them.  Of those, $3!$ have the largest digit first.

Comment: Got it. thanks.